# Problema al subir archivo a la web de Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

Tengo una gráfica de ejemplo. en el cual muestro la cantidad de mercados por zona(Lima).
entonces esta grafica lo quiero subir a web, y lo hago de la siguiente manera.

doy en publicar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego en la web de powerbi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me sale este mensaje que lo imposibilita
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A que se debe este problema, por que anteriormente lo podia subir normalmente y no me mostraba este mensaje y de frente adquiria el link.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Recientamente Power BI cambió la forma como se dan permisos para esta funcionalidad (publicar en la Web). Ahora el administrador debe activar de forma explícita el permiso de publicación. Para hacerlo (si eres administrador) debes ir a las opciones y luego pulsar sobre "Portal de administración"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y luego ir a la opción "Códigos para insertar". Allí verás un enlace que te llevará a la  "Configuración de Inquilinos"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez aquí, ya puedes otorgar los permisos que quieras en el apartado "Publicar en la Web"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Roger, he modificado mi pregunta, en la cual estoy agregando la foto de el portal de administracion. y no me sale la opcion de "Codigos para insertar" ... a que se debe esto?

Comment: Si la opción no te sale es que no tienes privilegios de administrador. Deberás buscar quién tiene asignado ese rol para que realice la modificación

Comment: Hola Roger, ¿como puedo tener privilegios de Administrador?, ya que entro de mi cuenta personal.

Comment: No estoy muy puesto en temas de administración, se que lo han cambiado con las nuevas áreas de trabajo, hay parte de la administración que se lleva desde O365. A ver si este enlace te ayuda https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/power-bi/service-manage-app-workspace-in-power-bi-and-office-365

Comment: Es una cuenta gratuita o Pro?

Comment: es una cuenta gratuita, pero hasta inicios de este año normal podia subir un archivo nuevo, ahora ya no se puede.

Comment: Entiendo que si lo puedes subir, lo que no puedes es luego obtener el código para compartirlo, o no es así?

Comment: exacto, es asi.

Comment: Revisa la documentación, a ver si encuentras el problema. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/power-bi/service-publish-to-web